# How can i call this function for each propertie i have in an array? React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I fetch an array witch apart from other properties, it looks something like this:

```
[{
  "res_id": 2,
  "res_address": "string"
 },{
  "res_id": 2,
  "res_address": "string"
 }]
```

I want to call this function for every res_address i have,to convert in coords and to then map then in a marker to show all my adresses in a map:

```
const FetchGeocoder = async (res_address) => {
        const response = await fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' +
            res_address + ',' +
            'CABA&key=' + "myKey")
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const res_coords = responseData.results[0].geometry.location;
        setAddressCoords(res_coords);
    };
```

I have tried to filter an foreach, but i get undefined,

I cant get it to work, if anyone can give me a hint or a solution it would mean a lot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't post your key here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not returning anything you don't need to wait `FetchGeocoder` do be done before calling each element of your array.

```
const list = [{
  "res_id": 2,
  "res_address": "string"
},{
  "res_id": 2,
  "res_address": "string"
}];


list.forEach(address => FetchGeocoder(address.res_address));
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, the forEach loop doesn't respect the `async` keyword. To `await` your `async` calls, you can replace the `forEach` function with a `for of` loop.

```
// res_addresses is your array
for(const res_address of res_addresses) {
    await FetchGeocoder(res_address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) . You are making an async call and I think you might be not waiting them to finish before setting coords if filter or foreach didn't work.
Just create an array of fetch calls and call all of them together with Promise.All, then setAddressCoords

Additionally, you can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of foreach or filter.